# Powerline has No Highlight/Color

Tags: vim-powerline

Powerline works perfectly in gvim, but any terminal emulator omits the color highlight, including konsole.

[image: Black and white powerline.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I needed CSApprox, available as [a vim script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) or [an AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vim-csapprox/).

Answer (score 3):

For me I had to add

```
set t_Co=256
```

to `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solution for me is to use "xterm-256" as the reported terminal type. (I'm using iterm2).